# How to play an audio file from JSON output?

Tags: mysql, avaudioplayer

I have an iOS app that outputs JSON information(from a mySQL database) in the form of a UITableView. This includes audio, images and text. While I can call the images and text, I am having trouble calling the audio (This is stored as a URL in the mySQL database) for example, this is the JSON output for the path to my audio file:

```
[{"audiopath = "http://my-website.com/audio/5552643-audio.caf"}]
```

This is the code I use to call the images and text but the audio isn't working. I have tried logging the path but it just comes up as NULL.

```
NSDictionary *words = [self.wordsArray objectAtIndex:index];
label.text = [words objectForKey:@"new"];

NSDictionary *images = [self.thumbArray objectAtIndex:index];
[imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];

NSDictionary *audio = [self.audioArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString:[audio objectForKey:@"audiopath"]];
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path error:nil];
NSLog(@"PATH:%@", path);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

The audio is stored on my server so it is not included in the app bundle.. does that mean I need to download the file into my app? or is there another way? Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. This is how I can target the image path:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_wordDetail objectForKey:@"audiopath"]];
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData  error:NULL];
audioPlayer.delegate = self; 
[audioPlayer play];
```